# How to add last modified into header

Tags: magento-1.9, header

How to add last modified product date to product page header and last modified category date to category page header?

Answer (score 0):

Add Below code on your `header.phtml` file.

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_product')): 
    echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getUpdatedAt(); 
endif; 
if(Mage::registry('current_category')):
    echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getUpdatedAt();
endif; 
?>
```